# Create a binary matrix based on information given by an "Excel" table in the APL language

Tags: excel, matrix, apl

I have an APL challenge to solve.
I received information in a table (Excel) in which the lines represent equipment and the columns represent the days of a year. In each cell I have information on the number of hours that this equipment will receive maintenance.

When the table cell has a value of 0, it means that there will be no maintenance and the equipment will be working all day. When the table cell has a value other than 0, it means that this value represents the equipment maintenance hours.

For example, I show a piece of that table below as example:

| Equipment / Data | 01/jan/20 | 02/jan/20 | 03/jan/20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Equipment 1 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| Equipment 2 | 0 | 12 | 8 |
| Equipment 3 | 8 | 12 | 8 |

But, I need to create a matrix where the columns are the equipment and each row represents the minutes of the dates in the other table ... and each day should be transformed into: 24 hours x 60 minutes = 1440 lines (527040 lines for a bissest year ). And each element will have a value of 1 for the equipment working and 0 for the equipment not working.

In addition, there are rules to compose the distribution of maintenance hours:

1. If the cell has a value other than 0 and the previous and later
   dates have a value of 0, the start of maintenance will be at 00:00.
   Using the example table, this happens on Equipment 1; then, in the
   final matrix, in column 1 of row 1 to 1440 the value 1 will be
   placed; from row 1441 to 1921 (representing the 8 o'clock in the
   table) the value of 0 will be placed and then the value of 1 until
   the end of this matrix (row 4320).
2. If the cell has a value other than 0 and also at a later date,
   the hours must meet. Using the example table, this happens on
   Equipment 2; then, in the final matrix, in column 2 of row 1 to
   2161, the value 1 will be placed; from row 2161 to 3361
   (representing 12 o'clock on one day and 8 o'clock on the other
   consecutive day in the table) the value of 0 will be placed and then
   the value of 1 until the end of this matrix (row 4320).
3. If the cell has a value other than 0 and also in the next two
   days; join the first two days. Using the example table, this happens
   on Equipment 3; then, in the final matrix, in column 3 of row 1 to
   960 the value 1 will be placed; from line 961 to 2161 (representing
   8 o'clock on one day and 12 o'clock on the other consecutive day in
   the table) the value of 0 will be placed; from row 2162 to 2880 the
   value of 1; from row 2881 to 3361 (representing the 8 hours of the
   last day) and then the value of 1 until the end of this matrix (row
   4320).

There may be several days when the equipment will be stopped (value of 24 in the table cells), but as long as they follow the rules above, that's fine.

I'm a beginner with the APL language, so I thought of starting as follows:

```
t ← 3 3 ⍴ 0 8 0 0 12 8 8 12 8   ⍝ just to test, in the real case I will import the excel table
(nc nd) ← ⍴ t                   ⍝ the number of rows in the table will be the number of columns (nc) of the matrix and the number of days will generate the number of its rows (nr)
nr ← nd × 24 × 60               ⍝ calculation of the number of rows
m ← nr nc ⍴ 1                   ⍝ creating the matrix with all values equal to 1
```

I managed to think so far ... and I had several doubts about this beginning of the code above:

1. how could it interact with matrix t, after all the rules need to
   be researched in matrix t?
2. how to insert the values 0 in the matrix m, since I started the
   matrix m with all the elements equal to 1?
3. would this be the best strategy to deal with this problem?

So, could you help me with this problem?

Comment: It would help to know which implementation and version of APL you use.

Comment: The implementation is APL2000.
Are there severe differences between implementations?

Comment: Yes, [some have new primitives](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Learning_resources#Haven.27t_used_APL_in_a_while.3F) that others don't have. APL2000 has a quite limited vocabulary, but its documentation isn't publicly available, so it hard to know exactly. Answers will have to be extremely conservative…

Comment: I see ... Anyway, it seems to me to be a little more basic problem in terms of what is needed as primitives ... maybe with an If / Then / Else logic it will solve. I just thought that using this "directives" from APL would be easier and help in learning.

Do you have any interesting material with matrix manipulation?

Comment: I think you  *can* do something elegant in APL, but I simply have not had time to answer yet. Planning  on doing so soon, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's get your questions out of the way:

> 1. how could it interact with matrix t, after all the rules need to be researched in matrix t?

Right, this might be involved. I think it is easier to construct the result directly, rather than to modify a pre-made matrix.

> 2. how to insert the values 0 in the matrix m, since I started the matrix m with all the elements equal to 1?

Modified assignment is your friend there: `m[row;column]←1` would change a specific bit.

> 3. would this be the best strategy to deal with this problem?

I don't think so. Rather, let's create the result matrix directly from the input matrix…

---

To limit the amount of data, let's solve this problem as if your result matrix needed one row per hour, not per minute. We'll make the trivial adjustment for minutes at the end.

Each day will consist of two periods; one for maintenance and one for work. One of these periods could have length zero, but that is irrelevant. In the result, `1` indicates a time unit of work and `0` a time unit of maintenance. This means that every day can be represented with two 2-element vectors, namely time-counts, and `1 0` for work before maintenance or `0 1` for maintenance before work. The two elements in the time-counts add up to the total number of time units in a day (24 for now, 1440 later). If we let the time-counts replicate (`/`) the Boolean vector, we get a moment-by-moment indication of whether the equipment is working or not.

Normally, we want maintenance before work, i.e. `0 1`, but if we also have maintenance tomorrow, and today is an odd-numbered day in a run of maintenance days, then we want to swap the order.

Let's start by defining the scaling so we can move from 24 to 1440 time units per day later:

```
scale ← 1
unitsPerDay ← 24 × scale
maintUnits ← maintUnits × scale
```

We compute the number of work units per day, create a Boolean matrix for the maintenance days, and look for where `1 1` subarrays begin, which indicates days that have maintenance tomorrow:

```
workUnits ← unitsPerDay - maintUnits
maintDay ← × maintUnits
maintTomorrow ← 1 1 ⍷ maintDay
```

In order to find out which days we swap, we need to find out the running parity in each run of `1`s. We could partition the data and apply `≠\¨` on the partitions, but there's a clever and more performant way to do this. From the [FinnAPL idiom library](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/FinnAPL_idiom_library), we find how to apply `≠\` on subvectors:

| 351. | Running parity (≠) over subvectors of Y indicated by X | `X←B1; Y←B1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | `≠\Y≠X\A≠¯1↓0,A←X/≠\¯1↓0,Y` |  |

But to indicate where the subvectors begin, we need to isolate the first `1` in each run of `1`s:

| 633. | First ones in groups of ones | `X←B1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | `X>¯1↓0,X` |  |

We'll name these utilities `SegRunParity` and `FirstOfRun` for clarity. Enclosing along the last axis, transforms our matrices into vectors of vectors, so we can apply `SegRunParity` on each corresponding two vectors. When we're done, we mix (`⊃`) the result back into a matrix. Now we know when to swap; when there's maintenance tomorrow, and today is an odd-numbered day:

```
firstOfRun ← FirstOfRun maintDay
oddInRun ← ⊃ (⊂[2] firstOfRun) SegRunParity¨ (⊂[2] maintUnits)
swap ← maintTomorrow ∧ oddInRun
```

We construct two 3D arrays, with the same leading shape as the input (number of equipment, number of days) but with a trailing axis of length 2, to fit in two periods (maintenance-then-work or work-then-maintenance) per day. This will allow us to swap along the trailing axis where necessary, before we combine the two trailing axes into a single axis of periods. The first array will hold the time unit counts for maintenance then work (but we may swap them), so we construct it by laminating the two matrices along a new axis after axis 2. The second array holds the corresponding activity for that period, so it has the same shape, with every row being `0 1` (unless we swap). Each 3D array is then rotated 0 or 1 steps along its last axis with the corresponding value from our swapping matrix:

```
count ← ,[2 3] swap ⌽[3] maintUnits ,[2.5] workUnits
act ← ,[2 3] swap ⌽[3] ((⍴ maintUnits) , 2) ⍴ 0 1
```

Finally, we again enclose the last axis of our counts and activity matrices, so we can apply replicate between corresponding vectors, before we mix the result back into a matrix. I'm using a cover function for `/` because I don't know if it is a function or an operator in APL2000, and if it is an operator, then we cannot apply `¨` to it directly. Since you want columns instead of rows, we have to transpose the result:

```
work ← ⍉ ⊃ (⊂[2] count) Replicate¨ (⊂[2] act)
```

---

Here is all the code:

```
∇ R←X SegRunParity Y;A
  R←≠\Y≠X\A≠¯1↓0,A←X/≠\¯1↓0,Y
∇

∇ R←FirstOfRun X
  R←X>0 ¯1↓0,X
∇

∇ R←X Replicate Y
  R←X/Y
∇

∇ work←Work maintUnits;scale;unitsPerDay;workUnits;maintDay;maintTomorrow;firstOfRun;oddInRun;swap;count;act

  scale ← 1
  unitsPerDay ← 24 × scale
  maintUnits ← maintUnits × scale
 
  workUnits ← unitsPerDay - maintUnits
  maintDay ← × maintUnits
  maintTomorrow ← 1 1 ⍷ maintDay
    
  firstOfRun ← FirstOfRun maintDay
  oddInRun ← ⊃ (⊂[2] firstOfRun) SegRunParity¨ (⊂[2] maintUnits)
  swap ← maintTomorrow ∧ oddInRun
    
  count ← ,[2 3] swap ⌽[3] maintUnits ,[2.5] workUnits
  act ← ,[2 3] swap ⌽[3] ((⍴ maintUnits) , 2) ⍴ 0 1
  work ← ⍉ ⊃ (⊂[2] count) Replicate¨ (⊂[2] act)
∇
```

---

It is easier to verify the result if we decorate it with two columns on the left, containing a day number and hour number, and add a header row indicating *day*, *hour*, and equipment numbers:

```
(equips days) ← ⍴ t
dayNums ← 24 / ⍳ days
hourNums ← (days × 24) ⍴ ¯1 + ⍳ 24
header ← 'DH' , ⍳ equips
header ,[1] dayNums , hourNums , Work t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPPi9NAFL7PX/Fum2DWpkmFhYBQWAVh1VKVTen2MDTZbTBNajKh9Kqwv7CLIOJJ8KY3Dy548rL@J/OP1DcvnWSKSGky8973vu97byZ8ke5HK57mZxt58@npkTz/4INcf4FH8yrlIob@4MhzXXcjLy9giNkQXsRnwyob8CIRKxgFfQaUkFdfT0b4CE/6@Lz70ZXnH12nr0o6KqcjI4ZUjGm@x0lRiuenyAjhlil86IJGh7voEIbxIk2mytlIwzsG5TIvXmPsGF8w50kmXmWJKINyytM4qNR6EBeHfBUoYJ0jmArR4mU@z4siXwanjbEgj6InmVqUS74IpnmViYBPBUMDRAyoCF3cGQIU83rw53ONwWzrh5LGtgUhrHFGKJNy36jRfFoKKf5N6mZqg/iT619NGYJA6bWNEsw4EAOpR0AQef0OLHn9duxNjGp752bcfW8grS9bTQxn2PbfOrz81ohoZzRpwjpjD/zJtvb977Fvsqrs/QeTdnBYisfzv0LLkutb0xQ44Nmggi6douKp@1xf7fRKfuz2Cho9op6tLuBmU@v64G8ZD/CPvB4uDujFrPhNlSxKiPgKxWuhWxAM98@qealvTgfDPwnEZnlVNClLhdR5e73aNX4rcI/AXo/NYh7FBQH3Dmd72JtK1Io66Yy7E9BqDjTsDtB3I/4C)

As you've probably guessed, we can change the time unit from hours to minutes by adjusting `scale` from `1` to `60`, and making the corresponding adjustments to our decorations. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPPi9NAFL7nr3i3TTBr06QuCwGhsArCqqUqpnR7GJrsNpgfNZlQelXYX1gRRDwJ3vTmQcGTl/U/mX@kvnnJJFNFSieT933ve9@beWHLZD9csyQ/24q3Hx4ei/N3HojNJ7iXVgnjEQxHx67jOFtxeQFjRAN4Ep2Nq2zEipivYeIPDSBAXH0@meASnAxxvfnWF@fvHXsoU3oSU5GJgVKGofTux0XJH5@iIgSNUnDXAcUOdtkBjKNlEs@ls4mi9zTJVV68wNhzfEDK4ow/y2Je@uWcJZFfyf0oKo7Y2pfEGiOaDNHmaZ7mRZGv/NPWmJ@H4YNMbsoVW/rzvMq4z@bcQAMkDFgRDhx81SpQ0B3A7481CdHOEIHaa0dCWmuNWLrkvpaj9FQplPgXVN0Qo48/sfnZpiEJZL2uU6JpN6Ix1RkQRVy/BlNcv5q6My3b2hmNm68tpfNlySPDQ@z67xxefmmLKGd01MS1py54syb3za@pp6tK9PadWXdwmIr3879E0xSbH7opsMG1QAYd6DcXUPe5udrplfxY3QxqPWI9S07gdlvX9cBrFA/xj7oubg7pYZjRyypelhCyNRanOaEyks8NjD6q0rIZKujJIeoh9p34xiKvil3clHF5/@6g7gI/HrhFGe7ASOOspWtMuR44f/NxiBcRC6OC6HtHi3QPD0citWWF2tP@DJRRG1pPNjTlbKBPkP8B)

Comment: I think that part
`(equips days) ← 2 ⊃ ⍴ t`
the correct would be
`(equips days) ←  ⍴ t`
Since the columns in the table represent the days and the lines the equipment... in the example I gave, coincidentally, they are the same.

Comment: Every day I see a code written in APL I see how interesting this language is.
I tested it here and it worked well in Dyalog (I downloaded it to learn better APL).
Your answer was incredible, very didactic. I confess that I am still trying to understand the code, but it is part of learning.

Comment: @RodrigoMiranda Yes, that was a typo. Fixed now. This code should work in APL2000 too. If you're using Dyalog APL, then a few things can be neater. E.g. `/` is a function, allowing `/¨` and the pattern `⊃ (⊂[2] X) f¨ (⊂[2] Y)` is simply `X(f⍤1)Y` while both `,[2 3]` and `,[1]` are just `⍪`. Everything can also be written using a modern lambda syntax. If you want further explanation of any part of the code, just let me know.

Comment: I'm trying to write the code in APL2000 v18.
But, I have some difficulties.and I will make a list of doubts:

1 - How does this expression work in the APL?
Do you have any material that explains how to use this?  <br/>

`work←Work maintUnits;scale;unitsPerDay;workUnits;maintDay;maintTomorrow;firstOfRun;oddInRun;swap;count;act`

Comment: 2 - You define `maintUnits ← maintUnits × scale`, but you don't have _maintUnits_ defined before ... So, theoretically you would be multiplying _scale_ by 0, right?
How does this work in Dyalog? In APL2000 it doesn't work.

`scale ← 1`
`unitsPerDay ← 24 × scale`
`maintUnits ← maintUnits × scale`

Comment: @RodrigoMiranda Putting blocks of code between pairs of `∇` is the traditional way to denote a function definition. The first line is [the header](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Defined%20Functions%20and%20Operators/TradFns/Model%20Syntax.htm), declaring calling syntax and locals. So `work←Work maintUnits;…` declares a function `Work` which calls its argument `maintUnits`. That variable is then used in the body of the function.

Comment: @RodrigoMiranda By the time we reach `maintUnits ← maintUnits × scale` then `maintUnits` has as value whatever argument `Work` was called with. APL variables never default to a specific value when not set explicitly. I don't have access to APL2000, but you should be able to enter `∇work←Work maintUnits;…` into the interactive session, finishing with a `∇`. Alternatively, I'm sure there's a system command or function that'll let you open an editor. Maybe there's even a menu item for it.